# Le langage approprié pour justifier une période de chômage

Tags: correspondance

Même s'il paraît que cette question appartient plutôt au domaine du coaching en recherche d'emploi (ou a la psychologie des chômeurs), j'ai décidé de la poser ici vu qu'une question posée de façon similaire, a été payante, et en termes de conseils, et en terme d'apprentissage linguistique.

Durant les 5 dernières années, je n'ai pas fait partie d'une équipe ou d'une entreprise. Je travaillais indépendamment sur des sites web, qui étaient mes propres idées, ou idées de proches, sans être vraiment rentables. Aujourd’hui, pour subvenir à mes besoins financiers, je trouve que j'ai un bagage technique qui va justifier ma réorientation de carrière, mais je trouve toujours une difficulté à rédiger ma lettre de motivation vu qu'en plus, le français n'est pas ma langue natale.

> Bonjour Madame, Monsieur,
>
> Je serai heureux si vous me donnez l'occasion d’entretenir avec vous
>   d’une possibilité de positionnement pour le poste "Développeur web
>   confirmé".  Suite à la lecture des compétences requises indiqués sur
>   votre annonce, je suis persuadé d'une intégration rapide au sein de
>   votre équipe faisant de notre collaboration une réussite partagée.
>
> Certes, mes stages et ma première expérience de travail m’ont permis
>   d’acquérir des bases solides en télécommunications, mais elles ont
>   surtout constitué l’occasion de côtoyer des professionnels et de
>   développer mes capacités de coopérer au sein d’une équipe. Durant
>   cette période très payante en terme de relationnel et gestion, le
>   niveau de la créativité et les challenges techniques, tous deux
>   caractéristiques d'un métier en informatique, m'ont beaucoup manqué.
>   J'ai alors pris en 2011 la décision de me réorienter vers le domaine
>   de ma passion: le web. J'ai pu donner des contributions significatives
>   dans la réalisation de sites en Wordpress, Prestashop et de me
>   spécialiser au développement avec Symfony. Ma grande volonté
>   d'amélioration est la qualité principale que je souhaite joindre aux
>   compétences de votre équipe.
>
> Mon curriculum vitae ci-joint vous donnera un aperçu complet de de mon
>   parcours, et je reste à votre entière disposition pour de plus amples
>   informations.
>
> Je vous prie d’approuver l’expression de ma haute considération et mes
>   salutations respectueuses.

Est-ce que la construction des phrases dans le deuxième paragraphe est correcte ?

Merci beaucoup pour votre temps

Comment: Une lettre de motivation peut être plus courte, et ne pas fournir les éléments qui seront repris dans le C.V. : Madame, Monsieur,  Je suis free-lance et j'ai réalisé 'x' sites Web qui m'ont permis de parfaire mon relationnel, tout en mettant mon efficacité au service de la qualité des produits livrés. J'envisage d'intégrer une équipe pour développer des projets plus importants  et maîtriser les méthodes rigoureuses (ou approfondir la méthode 'y' que j'utilise actuellement). J'espère vous rencontrer bientôt, et ainsi pouvoir m'intégrer rapidement dans un de vos projets.

Comment: Veuillez agréer l'expression de ma considération distinguée. -- Peut sembler un peu rapide, cela évite quelques formules verbeuses ou stéréotypées ; mais il faut que le C.V. soit très précis sur les logiciels, méthodes et langages maîtrisés, et dise exactement ce dont vous êtes capable de réaliser 'les yeux fermés'. -- Le problème de la personne qui va vous lire : mon projet doit être livré le ... compte tenu de ses connaissances, de ses motivations, on va le rencontrer... ou pas.

Comment: merci @cl-r. Je suis d'accord en ce qui concerne la verbosité de mon email.  Concernant le CV, j'ai suivi votre conseil en précisant les langages maîtrisés. Il me reste de trouver une formule professionnelle qui justifie un chômage de cette durée, l'absence d'un portfolio/references, et mon auto-formation en continue malgré cela. En tout cas, je serai questionné sur ce point lors d'un interview si ça n'a pas été trop visible sur la lettre. J’espère que les mots ont pu transmettre mon idée.

Comment: Pourquoi pas : j'ai pu prendre une période de congé sabbatique pour .... ?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers d'une manière général, en informatique, on a plus tendance à être souple concernant l'auto-apprentissage. Vous parlez de projets etc... il faudrait joindre un portefolio, qui doit bien exister à travers certains sites non ?

Comment: Merci @GautierC. Je trouve que cette souplesse concernant l'auto-apprentissage est ce que rassure le chercheur d'emploi (chômage de longue durée), le plus. Il resta a savoir comment formuler l'absence d'un vrai portfolio. En effet, le problème du portfolio c'est que le travail realisé en 5 ans, ou bien n'existe pas aujourdhui (car le client n'est plus interessé dans l'idee et ne paie pas l'hebergement) ou bien non maintenanue pour plus de 3 ans, ou bien éteint a cause d'un projet personnel non rentable..Je sais que mon cas est un peu extreme, mais je crois toujours que trouver les mots qui

Comment: @GautierC ....  les mots qui exprime positivement les aspects payant de cette période en terme d'apprentissage (car en vérité je n'ai jamais eu de temps sabbatique.. j'apprenais et je réalisais des choses mais en dehors d'une équipe  professionnelle). Merci beaucoup de m'aider a formuler les bonnes phrases pour cette situation.

Comment: Autodidacte, j'ai travaillé à la maitenance de l'application du projet *x* avant sa clôture, sur le projet temporaire *y* (destiné à une action marketing de 3 mois par ex.)... sur un projet intranet... Il s'agit ici de pouvoir montrer des courriels ou des factures montrant la véracité du projet, de sous-traitance ...

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers il serait bon de vous créer un site personnel consultable, montrant vos compétences en web. A noter que c'est très courant dans le milieu du web, et peut même remplacer votre CV (mais pas votre lettre de motivation)

Comment: @GautierC, Bonne idée, un site web personnel avec CV et quelque petits tutoriels ou je partage quelques connaissances.. je vous remercie beaucoup.

Comment: @cl-r. Je vous remercie pour votre temps et vos idées. C'est très apprécie.

Comment: Je trouve juste que la 1ère phrase ne te met pas beaucoup en valeur, et est un peu lourde en terme de construction pour une lettre de motivation : _Certes, mes stages et (...), mais elles ont surtout constitué l’occasion de côtoyer des professionnels et de développer mes capacités de coopérer au sein d’une équipe._
Tu peux peut-être le présenter autrement : _Ma première expérience dans le domaine des télécoms m'a permit de développer tels et tels capacités, compétences. Malgré cela, mon désir de créativité est resté inassouvi..._

Comment: @Kuruwan, merci. votre remarque est importante. C'est votre proposition que j'utiliserai dans le futur

Answer (score 2):

Voilà quelques suggestions perso pour essayer améliorer l'efficacité de cette lettre.

- Je ne mettrais pas "bonjour" au début de la lettre.
  L'incise normale est "Madame, monsieur".
- Je trouve les phrases un peu trop longues. Plus c'est simple et facile à lire, plus il y a de chances que la personne aille jusqu'au bout de la lettre (ce qu'elle n'est absolument jamais obligée de faire).
- Pour les mêmes raisons: aérer les paragraphes.
- *Je serai heureux si vous me donnez l'occasion d’entretenir avec vous d’une possibilité de positionnement pour le poste "Développeur web confirmé*" --> C'est trop tarabiscoté. *"Donner l'occasion d'entretenir avec d'une possibilité de positionnement*" est mal dit. On dit "*l'occasion de m'entretenir avec vous*. Il faudrait réécrire et simplifier au maximum.
- Une possibilité de positionnement pour le poste --> "positionnement pour le poste" est mal dit. Essaye de réécrire ceci, de le dire de façon plus simple.
- Suite à la lecture des compétences requises indiqué**E**s sur votre annonce, je suis persuadé d'une intégration rapide au sein de votre équipe faisant de notre collaboration une réussite partagée. --> Je suis sûre que tu peux faire une phrase plus simple, plus légère, plus courte, plus ***percutant***. Il faudrait citer les compétences par contre. Voire éventuellement les intégrer à une phrase ou à un petit ensemble de phrases. Par exemple, vous recherchez une personne ponctuelle: Je suis véhiculé, et j'habite à 2km de votre entreprise (ce n'est qu'un exemple) Etc, pour les compétences. Une qualité. Une preuve de qualité si possible, par des exemples de réalisation etc... Je suis le concepteur d'un site qui a attiré XXX visiteurs uniques par jour.
  On doit montrer que la lettre n'est pas un bête copié-collé des lettres précédemment envoyées à d'autres recruteur, il faut personnaliser, donner des détails. Sinon, autant prendre une lettre toute faite sur un site.
- "*Certes, mes stages et ma première expérience de travail m’ont permis d’acquérir des bases solides en télécommunications, mais elles ont surtout constitué l’occasion de côtoyer des professionnels et de développer mes capacités de coopérer au sein d’une équipe*." -> Phrase trop longue, qui fait 4 lignes, c'est énorme. La découper en 2 phrases serait plus agréable à lire. Le "Certes" n'est pas utile, c'est aussi bien sans.
- Mes *capacités à* coopérer."
- *"Durant cette période très payante en terme de relationnel et gestion, le niveau de la créativité et les challenges techniques, tous deux caractéristiques d'un métier en informatique, m'ont beaucoup manqué*"
  -> Alléger un peu, par exemple: Une période de ma vie qui fut très gratifiante du point de vue relationnel, et des défis à relever, inhérents aux métiers de l'informatique: Haute créativité, et challenges techniques.
  Je ne sais pas "si m'ont beaucoup manqué" est nécessaire, on ne voit pas très bien à quoi c'est relié.
- "J'ai alors pris en 2011 la décision de me réorienter vers le domaine de ma passion: le web. J'ai pu donner des contributions significatives dans la réalisation de sites en Wordpress, Prestashop et de me spécialiser au développement avec Symfony. "
  Réécrit, plus percutant, en écrivant au présent, et en mettant des verbes d'action à la place des substantifs: En 2011, j'ai décidé de me réorienter **dans** le domaine qui me passionne: le web. J'ai significativement contribué à la réalisation de sites sous Wordpress, Prestashop, et j'ai acquis de l'expertise dans le développement Symphony.
- Mon curriculum vitae -> Mon CV (pourquoi faire long et plus lourd? Les recruteurs manquent de temps.)
- Revoir la formule de politesse finale. Des exemples ont été donnés en commentaires.